# Verifying page title with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm running through Michael Hartl's [Rails Tutorial](http://railstutorial.org).

I'm trying to verify the title of my page.  The test looks like this:

```
it "should have the right title" do
      get 'home'
      response.should have_selector("title", :content => "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Home")
    end
```

The HTML head section looks like this

```
<head>
    <title>Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Home</title>
</head>
```

I'm getting the following failure

> 1) PagesController GET 'home' should
>   have the right title
>        Failure/Error: response.should have_selector("title", :content =>
>   "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App |
>   Home")
>        expected following output to contain a Ruby on Rails
>   Tutorial Sample App | Home
>   tag:
>        
>        # ./spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:13:in
>   `block (3 levels) in '

I'm expecting this to pass.  What am I doing wrong?  I'm using Rails 3 and RSpec 2.0.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Controller specs don't normally render the complete view, since they're intended to test controllers in isolation. You can tell Rspec to render the whole page by including the directive `integrate_views` at the top of the example group:

```
describe MyController do
  integrate_views
```

However you should ask yourself if you really want to do this, or if it would make more sense to write view specs.

btw you can also use the CSS3 selector syntax to save a few keystrokes (might need to include the Webrat matchers for this):

```
response.should have_selector("title:contains('Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Home')")
```

**EDIT**

For Rspec2, replace `integrate_views` with `render_views`

Comment: I tried putting the integrate_views directive at the top, but now I'm getting a syntax error

Comment: Oops, you must be on Rspec 2. Try `render_views`.

Comment: Thanks, maybe just edit your answer to say you should use render_views on Rspec 2?

Answer (score 3):

This question looks old, which explains why there is now a better way.

The following works well for me:

```
it "has the correct page title", js: true do
  visit "/users/sign_in" # for example
  expect(page.title).to include "Sign In or Create a New Account"
end
```

Comment: Also, you should be very careful when using the `include` method in this case.
If you have that string in the title it will pass, however, there might be undesired things as well. 
I'd recommend using the `eq` method in this case, as it will fail if it is not the exact string being passed.

Answer (score 2):

I found it easier to move to Capybara (I'm using Rails 3.0.1, Rspec 2.0.1, Ruby 1.9.2). Now you can do something like

```
page.should have_css('title', :text => 'Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Home')
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suspect you have a typo somewhere.

As of this instant, I'm working through Exercise 4 of Chapter 11. Every, single problem I've had with the tutorial turned out to be a typo on my part.

Note: I'm not cutting and pasting. I'm punching in all the code by hand.

Comment: I did the copy-paste thing...  And it worked perfectly once I put render_views at the top