# have_selector testing page title does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, title

I have the following codes for testing

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe PagesController do
render_views

describe "GET 'home'" do
 it "returns http success" do
  get 'home'
  response.should be_success
 end

 it "should have the right title" do 
  get 'home'
  response.should have_selector("title", :content => "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Home")
 end
end
```

But when I run rspec spec/ I have error validating the page title. I have modified the home.html.erb into this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Home</title>

</head>
<body>
    <h1>Sample App Home Page</h1>
    <p>Find me in app/views/pages/home.html.erb</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I have 
rspec version 2.13.0
capybara version 2.1.0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Verifying page title with rspec](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3971449/verifying-page-title-with-rspec)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
response.should have_content "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Home"
```

Comment: I still have the following errors:


<-[31mrspec ./spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:12<-[0m <-36m#PagesController GET 'home' should have the right title<-[0m
<-[31mrspec ./spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:25<-[0m <-36m#PagesController GET 'contact' should have the right title<-[0m
<-[31mrspec ./spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:38<-[0m <-36m#PagesController GET 'contact' should have the right title<-[0m